# How to generate SQL query from arithmetic relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would you parse (that's a simple case) something like that: `${table_1} + ${table_2} + ${table_3}`
and generate a sql query such as:

`WITH 
TMP_1 AS (SELECT date, quantity FROM table_1),
TMP_2 AS (SELECT date, quantity FROM table_2),
TMP_3 AS (SELECT date, quantity FROM table_3)

SELECT time_bucket('1 day', date) AS date,
    sum(quantity) AS sum FROM
    (
    SELECT date, quantity FROM TMP_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, quantity FROM TMP_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, quantity FROM TMP_3
    ) AS res_1
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1;`

Do you know of any kind of pseudo language that can be transformed to SQL queries

**Update 1**

The relation can change depending on user input: `${table_1} + ${table_2} * ( ${table_3} * 60 )`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with sql itself:

```
do
$$
declare
 _i text;
 _r text;
begin
 _i := '${table_1} + ${table_2} + ${table_3}';
 _r := (
   with u as (select * from unnest(string_to_array(_i,'+')) with ordinality t(e,o))
  , c as (select format('TMP_%s AS (SELECT date, quantity FROM %I)'
  , o
  , substring(unnest(string_to_array(e,'+')) from '\{(.+)\}')
  ) from u
)
select string_agg(format,','||chr(10)) from c);
 _r := 'WITH '||chr(10)||_r||chr(10)||$s$SELECT time_bucket('1 day', date) AS date,
    sum(quantity) AS sum FROM
    (
    SELECT date, quantity FROM TMP_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, quantity FROM TMP_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT date, quantity FROM TMP_3
    ) AS res_1
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 1;$s$;
 raise info '%',_r;
 execute _r;
end;
$$
;
```